# Echo post count of CPT with current taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have a CPT called 'Athlete' and a Taxonomy called 'School'.

Two sample terms have been added called 'term1' and 'term2'.

When a user views the archive for any of the 2 terms (taxonomy-school.php), I need to be able to echo the current post count of posts from within the Athlete CPT that contain the currently viewed taxonomy term.

So basically something like this:

```
<?php echo count_posts ('athlete', 'school', $currentTaxTerm); ?>
```

Is this possible, appreciate any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your taxonomy archive template, just add the following:

At the top: `global $wp_query;`

Then to get the post count for the entire term:

`echo $wp_query->found_posts`

This will display all posts in the query, which in a taxonomy template will be all posts attached to a term.

[WP Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties)

Answer (score -2):

When you get into the loop on the archive page, you can do this :

```
if(have_posts()) {
  echo found_posts() . " total posts";
}
while(have_posts()) {

  // display each post

}
```

Comment: [`found_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods) doesn't seem to be in the list of available WP Query Methods and I couldn't get this to work on a taxonomy archive template.